# What's wrong with my C code(My output is volatile because of malloc)?

Tags: c, malloc

I SOMETIMES get errors when executing this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int digits(int n){
    int count = 0;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        n/=10;             /* n=n/10 */
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

int fib(int n){
    int r;
    if(n == 1 || n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(n == 2)
        return 1;
    r = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    return r;
}

void function(void){
    char* test;     //number you want to scan
    int* table; 
    int length, length2, test2 = 0, number, l, random = 0, j = 1, buffer;
    test = malloc(sizeof(test));
    table = malloc(sizeof(table));
    scanf("%s", test);
    number = atoi(test);
    length = strlen(test);      //length of input test number
    while(test2 < length + 1){
        printf("fib(%d) = %d\n", j, fib(j));
        buffer = table[j - 1] = fib(j);
        test2 = digits(buffer);
        j++;
    }
    //input size of "table" into "length2"
    length2 = j - 1;
    for(l = 0; l < length2; l++){
        if(table[l] == number){
            printf("YES\n");
            random = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(random == 0)
        printf("NO\n");
    free(table);
    free(test);
}

int main(void){
    int num, i;
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for(i=0; i < num; i++){
        function();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
3
2
fib(1) = 0
fib(2) = 1
fib(3) = 1
fib(4) = 2
fib(5) = 3
fib(6) = 5
fib(7) = 8
fib(8) = 13
YES
*** Error in `./Am_I_a_Fibonacci_Number': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08384018 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

First number is to count how much input the user wants, (in this case 3) and the 2nd(in this case, 2nd, 3rd and 4th) number is the number you want to test whether its a Fibonacci number or not.
Sorry if this is very hard-to-read code, I have a lot to learn.

Comment: You're not `malloc`ating a proper amount of memory. Allocated amounts should be something like `sizeof (char) * somesize`, and `sizeof (int) * anothersize`; now you're allocating just enough to store your pointer.

Comment: You also don't really need to use malloc at all in this program.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks! Now I understand. When I write it like that, I'm allocating a block of memory equal to the size of my POINTER, not the actual size of the things I want to store in memory pointed to by the variable.

Comment: @KurtStutsman Really? How(I think I should figure out that myself...)???

Comment: For test you could simply use a char array.  Or even better just use `scanf("%d", &number)`. You also don't need table. You can print the the values of Fibonacci as you search for a match. You can stop once the Fibonacci value is greater than your search parameter.

Comment: @KurtStutsman I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allocating enough memory, thus you corrupt the heap. `sizeof()` applied on a pointer (as in your program) usually results in 4 or 8, depending on the architecture. Obviously, this might just be enough for `test`, but is definitely too little for `table`.

You need to figure out how much memory you really need, and use this as argument in `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

```
test = malloc(sizeof(test));
table = malloc(sizeof(table));
```

"test" is a variable of type char*. Such a variable has typically a size of 4 or 8 bytes. So you allocate memory for 4 or 8 bytes, which is enough for 4 or 8 chars.

"table" is a variable of type int*. Again, typically 4 or 8 bytes. Allocating 4 or 8 bytes is usually enough for 1 or two int's. If you try to store more, things will go badly wrong.

Figure out how many chars and ints you want to allocate, then call for example table = malloc (required_elements * sizeof (int)).